# The set of all strings with even number of ‘aba’ over alphabet { a,b }

Tags: regex

This is what I've come up with but it leaves out strings such as "baaabba", "bbbaaabba"...

```
b*a*((aba)a*b*(aba)a*)*b*
```

Comment: How many `'aba'`s are in `'ababa'`?

Answer (score 2):

#### No `aba`

First, let's see how we would match a string with **no `aba`s** at all. You'd want something like this:

```
(b|a+bb)*(a*b*)
```

At each point, we can match `b`s, but we need to look out for `a` - we can match an `a` (or a block of `a`s) only if it is followed by `bb`. Lastly, near the end of the string, we are free to match a block of `a`s and a block of `b`s.

#### Exactly One `aba`

Next, let's look at words with **one `aba`**. This is very similar to what we had before:

```
(b|a+bb)*(a+ba(b|a+bb)*)(a*b*)
```

We have the same pattern with `(a+ba(b|a+bb)*)` added in the middle - `a+ba` is our `aba` block, and `(b|a+bb)*` after it is again a block of `a`s and `b`s which doesn't contain `aba`.
Note that the inner group (the parentheses around `a+ba(b|a+bb)*`) isn't needed - it's there for readability.

#### Exactly Two `aba`s

```
(b|a+bb)*(a+ba(b|a+bb)*)(a+ba(b|a+bb)*)(a*b*)
```

#### Even Number of `aba`s

```
(b|a+bb)*(a+ba(b|a+bb)*a+ba(b|a+bb)*)*(a*b*)
```

Similar to the previous one, but with a star around the inner group.

Comment: It's quite possible I've overlooked something and have a error somewhere, but the logic of slowly complicating the pattern should be correct. I hope. Oh, and when testing in a programming language, don't forget `^` and `$`! `:)`

Answer (score 1):

This one `^(((?!aba)[ab])*(aba((?!aba)[ab])*aba)*)*$` will do the work.

I assumed that you want the `aba` substrings not to overlap. In other words `ababa` is not a match.

Comment: I'm not sure if the OP wants the string to contain _only_ a's and b's.  If he does you might want to change your `.` to `[ab]`.

Comment: @ray he said over alphabet {a,b}